# How to SUM values for DISTINCT values of another column and GROUP BY date?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can we SUM `amount` for each `activity` only on same date and output a row for each `date`? This query is not working.

```
SELECT SUM(amount), type, date FROM table GROUP BY DISTINCT date;
```

**Table**

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
| id |    date    | activity  | amount  |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
| 1  | 2017-12-21 | Shopping  | 200     |
| 2  | 2017-12-21 | Gift      | 240     |
| 3  | 2017-12-23 | Give Away | 40      |
| 4  | 2017-12-24 | Shopping  | 150     |
| 5  | 2017-12-25 | Give Away | 120     |
| 6  | 2017-12-25 | Shopping  | 50      |
| 7  | 2017-12-25 | Shopping  | 500     |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
```

**Required Result**

```
+------------+-----------+------+-----------+
|    date    | Shopping  | Gift | Give Away |
+------------+-----------+------+-----------+
| 2017-12-21 | 200       | 240  |           |
| 2017-12-23 |           |      | 40        |
| 2017-12-24 | 150       |      |           |
| 2017-12-25 | 550       |      | 120       |
+------------+-----------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: search mysql conditional aggregation and/or mysql pivot

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
select `date`, 
  sum(if (activity='Shopping', amount, null)) as 'Shopping',
  sum(if (activity='Gift', amount, null)) as 'Gift',
  sum(if (activity='Give Away', amount, null)) as 'Give Away'
from table
group by `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It returns exact result that you want

```
SELECT t.date,
    SUM(t.shopping_amount) AS shopping,
    SUM(t.gift_amount) AS gift,
    SUM(t.give_away_amount) AS give_away
FROM
(
    SELECT p.`date`, p.`activity`, p.`amount` AS shopping_amount,
        0 AS gift_amount, 0 AS give_away_amount
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.`activity` = 'Shopping'

    UNION

    SELECT p.`date`, p.`activity`, 0 AS shopping_amount,
        p.amount AS gift_amount, 0 AS give_away_amount
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.`activity` = 'Gift'

    UNION 

    SELECT p.`date`, p.`activity`, 0 AS shopping_amount,
        0 AS gift_amount, p.amount AS give_away_amount
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.`activity` = 'Give Away'
) t
GROUP BY t.date
```

Comment: Seems to be more query here than is strictly necessary

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you can't pivot your results into column headers unless you know all possible values as demonstrated by slaasko but you can get the results using sql into a form which can be pivoted using your display tool ( e.g. slice of BI tool).

```
SELECT SUM(amount), activity, date FROM table GROUP BY date, activity;
```

Comment: Well, you can. It's just a bit more complicated